# $0-1$ permanent that equals exactly $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permanent

Let $M$ be an $n\times n$ with elements $\in\{0,1\}$.

Using the fact that interchanging any rows or colums of the matrix does not change its permanent, it is possible to show that $Perm(M) > 0$ iff you can interchange rows and columns of $M$ in a way that its main diagonal is filled with $1$'s.

However, in which case can we say that $Perm(M)=1$? It is possible to show that (assuming $M$ has only $1$'s on its main diagonal) if $\exists m\exists k:$ $\{m$-th row or column of the matrix contains at least $2$ $1$'s$\}$ $\land\forall i\in[1;n]:M_{k,i}\ge M_{m,i}$, then $Perm(M)>1$. But are there cases when this condition is false and still $Perm(M)>1$?

Comment: @user1551, permanent is allowed to be arbitrarily large, only elements of the matrix are either $0$ or $1$. I.e. the largest permanent would be $n!$

Comment: @user1551, edited the question. Hope now I can define permanent over the set of natural numbers, while the elements of matrix can be only $0$ or $1$.

Comment: I think the condition for permanent exceeding $1$ (assuming an all-ones diagonal) is that there be at least two nonzero entries that are neither in the same row nor in the same column.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Two off-diagonal such entries, I assume you mean.

Comment: @Jair yes, or perhaps I should have written, two *additional* nonzero entriesthat are neither etc., etc.

Comment: Any thoughts on my comments, rus?

Comment: @Gerry, apparently, that's right. And likely is equivalent to my statement.

Comment: Unfortunately, I just realized that the condition I gave is wrong. $$\pmatrix{1&0&0\cr0&1&1\cr1&0&1\cr}$$ satisfies the condition of having two nonzero off-diagonal entries that aren't in the same row and aren't in the same column, but the permanent is still just $1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, hm, fair. Does not satisfy my condition as well.